# How can I print the most frequent word in a text using bufferedreader and treemap ? - Java

Tags: java, arrays, string, bufferedreader, treemap

The text will contain only spaces and words.

Sample input:

```
thanks for the help \n
the car works now   \n
thanks              \n
```

Output:
the -  because it is lexicographic smaller than " thanks".

```
 public class Main {
     public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
         String line;
         String[] words = new String[100];
         Map < String, Integer > frequency = new HashMap < > ();
         BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
         while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
             line = line.trim();
             if (!line.isEmpty()) {
                 words = line.split("\\W+");
                 for (String word: words) {
                     String processed = word.toLowerCase();
                     processed = processed.replace(",", "");

                     if (frequency.containsKey(processed)) {
                         frequency.put(processed,
                             frequency.get(processed) + 1);
                     } else {
                         frequency.put(processed, 1);
                     }
                 }
             }
         }
         int mostFrequentlyUsed = 0;
         String theWord = null;

         for (String word: frequency.keySet()) {
             Integer theVal = frequency.get(word);
             if (theVal > mostFrequentlyUsed) {
                 mostFrequentlyUsed = theVal;
                 theWord = word;
             } else if (theVal == mostFrequentlyUsed && word.length() <
                 theWord.length()) {
                 theWord = word;
                 mostFrequentlyUsed = theVal;
             }

         }
         System.out.printf(theWord);
     }
 }
```

I'm failing one test  and I really don't know why that's why I needed another method.

Comment: Can you provide a code example of what you have tried.

Comment: I've added my solution, maybe I can find another method...

Comment: @GeorgeChetan, please format your code and make it more readable

Comment: @HarshalParekh Sorry...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the title of your question you mention TreeMap but you are actually not using it.

If you replace the line where you instantiate the map with

```
         NavigableMap < String, Integer > frequency = new TreeMap < > ();
```

Then you can replace the for loop with a single query to the map:

`System.out.println(frequency.lastEntry().key)`

You can read the documentation here: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/TreeMap.html#lastEntry--

Comment: But what if I have an input like this: "car  thanks car thanks thanks". The output will be "car" because is smaller  lexicographic  than " thanks". It doesn't matter if "car" appears less than "thanks".  So basically if I have more words that appear more than once I have to display the smallest frequent word. What can I modify in my code?

Comment: You're right. My solution doesn't solve your problem. I missed something when I was answering it. In your original question you said you had one example wrong. Do you know what it is? You clean commas from the text, maybe you also need to clean other characters like `.!`? (Talking about this snippet: `processed.replace(",", "");`)

Comment: I really don't know ,my solution is failing one test out of 5.It tells me that the text will contain only spaces and lowercase and uppercase letters of the English alphabet.

Comment: I've found the problem.It seems like if my word is "Thanks" it will print me "thanks". What can I add to solve this problem? If my word starts with an uppercase letter I need to leave it that way.

Comment: `toLowerCase` makes the upper case characters lower case. So "Thanks" becomes "thanks". Removing the line that contains `word.toLowerCase()` would fix that, but it also means that "Thanks" and "thanks" would be counted as different words. There's no right or wrong here, it depends what you want to do...